# Jetpack Compose Button color is wrong

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change button color to be transparent but if I press it it will be semitransparent of certain color. But for some reason my button is purple (I dont even have purple color defined anywhere).
Color.kt

```
val colorAccept = Color(0x50C878)
val colorDecline = Color(0xD22B2B)
```

Button:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    
    val backgroundColor = if (userItem.isFollowed){ colorAccept
    } else { colorDecline }

    Button(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onClick = { onStateUpdate() },
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                color = backgroundColor.copy(alpha = if (isPressed) 0.4f else 0f),
                shape = CircleShape
            )
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = if (userItem.isFollowed) R.drawable.user_follow else R.drawable.user_unfollow),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = backgroundColor
        )
    }
```

If I modify it (using Material3) like this:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

    val backgroundColor = if (userItem.isFollowed){ colorAccept
    } else { colorDecline }

    Button(
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = backgroundColor.copy(alpha = if (isPressed) 0.4f else 0f),
            contentColor = backgroundColor
        ),
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onClick = { onStateUpdate() },
        shape = CircleShape
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = if (userItem.isFollowed) R.drawable.user_follow else R.drawable.user_unfollow),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
```

Purple color is gone but also is icon color. Simply what I want to achieve is that Icon color will be always static visible color but if I press Button transparent version of that Icon color will appear as background of Button.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Theme.kt` and find your `Composable` theme and set the parameter `dynamicColor: Boolean = false`. "I dont even have purple color defined anywhere" This is because you are using dynamic theme.

[Adding dynamic colors in app](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#4)

From now on, if don't change your button color will be `primaryColor` and your icon color will be `LocalContentColor.current` "This typically represents the on color for a color in ColorScheme. For example, if the background color is ColorScheme.surface, this color is typically set to ColorScheme.onSurface." So your icon color will be `onPrimary` because of it inside the `Button`

[Material 3](https://m3.material.io/)

You can find more information about Material 3 theme from the link above.

Comment: Yeah I solved this but I have an issue that I cant see button icon at all. I want from icon tint to be solid color but apparently my icon is transparent as button background. If I understand correctly containerColor is color of Button background (changing on press for my case) and contentColor is color of every component inside Button (like Icon in my case). But its not working.

Comment: `ContentColor` is the color of the `Button` inside. However, if you provide a `tint` value to the icon, the `tint` color will override the `contentColor` color. If you want, you can experiment with a different icon or utilize the `IconButton`component. Because i can't see any issue here.   [Icon buttons](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#IconButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.IconButtonColors,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0))

Comment: I havent used tint after all, but I fixed it doing this: contentColor = backgroundColor.copy(). Now Icon was right color. I don't understand why I have to use copy function because backgroundColor is solid color without any alpha.

Comment: I noticed when you said alpha. There is no alpha in the colors you have. Can you try adding alpha? Compose may not be resolving these colors.   `val colorAccept = Color(0xFF50C878)
val colorDecline = Color(0xFFD22B2B)`